# How to Delete the first 10 and last 10 rows of a SAS Data file?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide, rowdeleting

I am trying to delete the first ten and last ten of a SAS data file But I am not able to do this. By using the code below I am able to delete the last 10 rows but not the first 10.

```
data b;
set a NOBS=COUNT;

if count <= 10 then delete;
if count -_n_ < 10 then delete;
run;
```

Can someone please help me on this and provide your suggestions.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `_N_` variable with `NOBS` statement.

Delete first and last 5 rows in Class table:

```
data want;
set  sashelp.class  NOBS=COUNT;

if _n_        <= 5 then delete;
if count -_n_ <  5 then delete;
n_ = _n_;
run;
```